# When you have no money, doesn't that mean you're already bankrupt? Can you use "in general" for a case like that?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-order

Is the sentence below correct? What would be the best way to write it?

"In general, when you have no money, tap water is better than bankruptcy."

It says "in general" and assumes a condition "when you have no money" immediately after that. And again at the end it says "than bankruptcy" while "having no money" already implies that, are all the words in this sentence in proper order?

Context:

1. "One day, I even found myself asking my girlfriend for a few cents because I had no money to buy bottled water"
2. "In general, when you have no money, tap water is better than bankruptcy."
3. Source: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11336678

Comment: Bankruptcy is a legal condition and is quite different than having no money.

Comment: To add on to what others have said, they are related but not the same. Bankrupt usually means (metaphorically/outside of the legal definition) that you had money, have lost most of it and may even owe some still (you may actually have a lot more money than others but still be bankrupt). 'Broke' is the word used when you have hardly any money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having no money isn't the same as bankruptcy:  bankruptcy means you are unable to pay your debts, and need to declare yourself bankrupt, effectively asking the law to save you from the people you owe money to.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bankruptcy

Plenty of people have no money without going bankrupt.  Also, when people say that they "have no money" they are often exaggerating and really mean that they have no disposable income, but they are still able to pay their rent and bills.

I don't understand quite what point that quote is making.  If the alternative to tap water is expensive bottled water, which is a symbol of spending money on luxury items, then perhaps it could be rephrased as

*"When you have no money you are forced to make essential cutbacks in your spending, to avoid going so far into debt that you risk bankruptcy".*

Comment: It is not always a voluntary thing, a creditor (or creditors) can force the issue and apply to the court to have you made bankrupt. In any event you are not "bankrupt" until a court has declared you "bankrupt". At least that is the position in the UK.

Comment: Thanks for making the distinction.  I spent several years having very little or no money, but had no debts either.